# htaccess file won't redirect internal pages

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains, old.com and new.com.. I want to have all pages from old.com be 301 redirected to new.com and maintain the URL structure. So, if someone goes to old.com/about , they are redirected to new.com/about

As far as I can tell, everything in my htaccess file is correct. Here is the relevant section:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

However, it's only redirecting the home page. If you go to old.com it redirects properly to new.com , but if you go to old.com/about, the page is not redirected to new.com at all.

I am using linux cPanel hosting on Godaddy, and also using wordpress. One thing that may be causing the issue is that in the file manager for the domains, old.com is the directly in the public_html folder , and new.com is its own directory within, so the path is public_html -> old.com -> new.com. A different developer set this up, so I am trying to figure out how to correctly have all pages redirected properly.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Move this rule as your top rule

Comment: This worked and is the correct answer